# Passing data from local storage to Flask

Tags: flask, web, local-storage

I was wondering, How could I pass user data that was given through form into local storage and access it in Flask to use the data to display using Flask?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure, I have understood the question. Here is my answer based on what I have understood. To save and read data from client local storage you need to use the browser JavaScript.

```js
document.getElementById('clickme').onclick = function clicked() {
        // use ajax or equivalent  to send the data from the browser to the server
}
```

On the server read the data:

```py
@app.route("/route1")
def route1():
    data = request.get_json()['data']

    # do anything here

    return jsonify({'status':'success'})
```